# Touch vs tap events in Javascript - iOS mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mobile-safari

I have a container div I have set `touchstart`/`move`/`end` event listeners in order to scroll the content within it without the page scrolling.  Now my issue is how do you allow links within it to be clickable?  I am setting `e.preventDefault();` within my `touchstart` handler to prevent the page from jerking while scrolling and this is preventing my links from being clickable.  Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try binding to `touchmove` instead.  This will only be triggered if the user touches and then drags, so should not interfere with them clicking. (Tested [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kgV65/2/))

Comment: what if you just want to detect a tap?